# This iMessage application is missing its required iMessage app extension

Tags: ios, imessage

Using Xcode 8.0, running stickers app on iPhone (with iOS 10.0.2)  gives me this error:

`This iMessage application is missing its required iMessage app extension`

It runs fine on simulator. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Xcode 8.1 Beta .

Comment: first check you app id setting, your bundle id is same for extension or not like com.companyname.appname.extensionname , if all same then check your message setting on phone is imessage enable or not ? if enable the go to imessage store you will see manage tab tap on this and add your imessage app that are available , hope so it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check if your deployment target is less than your device iOS version. If you are running Xcode Beta with deployment target `10.1`, your device must be at least on same beta version. Reduce your deployment target to `10.0` otherwise.

Comment: You should change deployment target in both - app and extension.

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure that the deployment target in your Xcode 8 is less than or equal to your device iOS version. You need to change the deployment target in both the "Project" and "Targets" in your Xcode to make a successful build.