# iMessage Application is Missing its Required iMessage App Extension - Can Not Run on Device

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I have looked at [This iMessage application is missing its required iMessage app extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049478/this-imessage-application-is-missing-its-required-imessage-app-extension), however the answer is not fixing my problem.

My device is on iOS 10.0, and I want to target 10.0, not 10.1. So I set my deployment target to 10.0. I got the error shown in the image below. I then tried setting my target to iOS 9.3, but I still get the error below when I try to run my sticker app on my iPhone from Xcode 8.1.

[image]

I have set the deployment target in both build settings and general. What is wrong here?

Comment: What's the device OS version and what's the Xcode version you are using?

Comment: xcode 8.1 and iOS 10.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This iMessage application is missing its required iMessage app extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049478/this-imessage-application-is-missing-its-required-imessage-app-extension)

Answer (score 0):

1) iOS Deployment Target

The screenshot shows your `iOS Deployment Target` is 9.3. It has to be set to 10.0 or higher to support iMessage Extentions.

2) Target missing

Assure you have an Application- and a Extension target:

[image]